# How to fetch 2 times in MYSQL PDO without FETCHALL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop, fetch

I have this sample query:

```
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT id FROM table");
```

I want to get the first row and then loop and display all rows. So I use the following to get the first row:

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$first_row = $STH->fetch();
$first_row = $first_row['id'];
```

I use while loop to display all rows again:

```
while ($list = $STH->fetch()) {      
$id = $list['id'];
echo $id;
}
```

Now the while skips the first row and I want it to be displayed. Is there an equivalent to `mysql_data_seek` to reset the pointer again to the first row? I know `fetchall` can be used but it's bad on memory and wasteful. I could also run the query and limit to 1 but this is not recommended as I have a query that joins multiple tables and would be very slow. Is there any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take that back looks like you can use the cursor orientation contants to select the result... sample code coming... I havent tried this so you may need to play a bit. This is also based on the assumption that a `PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST` acts like a data_seek and leaves the cursor on the first position as opposed to returning it to whatever it was before.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id FROM table', array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$stmt->execute();

$first = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST);
$first_row = $first['id'];

// other stuff

// first iteration we rewind to the first record;
$cursor = PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST;

while (false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, $cursor))) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   // successive iterations we hit the "next" record
   $cursor = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT; 
   echo $id;
}
```

---

I dont think you can rewind a statement... Assuming these blocks arent seprated by a bunch of intermediary logic id just do it in the loop.

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // no need to pull an array
$count = 0;
while ($id = $STH->fetch()) {      
  if($count === 0) {
   $first_row = $id;
  }
  echo $id;
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: I need it to be in an array to use all the rows also I need to display the first row before the while to use it for another purpose...thanks :)

Comment: this is just a simplified query to explain the problem..the query is much bigger than that

Comment: wouldn't fetching the next row in the loop cause also performance problems even more than fetchALL?

Comment: How would that cause a performance issue? Thats essentially what it does normally... There may be slightly more overhead for using a scrollable cursor but its probably negligible. It might be an issue with using relative or absolute fetching where it needs to calculate or seek past a bunch of records but even then its probably not much since i think all this is done on the `C` side. Why dont you try it and find out? Since the answers you have so far are about the only way to do what you need to accomplish and they all have trade offs...

Comment: Thanks @prodigitalson for your help :) I will try it as well as another approach which is to echo the first row alone and then the while results...that way will get all the results together..the first result and all the others..wouldn't that also work?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel: I think that would work, but i think the example code in your question was oversimplified (ha! thats a first on SO!) so its hard to say. Worth a shot though.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use a `do...while` loop instead?

```
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$list = $STH->fetch();
$first_id = $list['id'];

do {
  $id = $list['id'];
  echo $id;
} while ($list = $STH->fetch());
```

Comment: for some reason this ignores the ORDER BY in the query...thanks :)

Comment: @Michael - really? I'm not seeing how this could have any effect on the `order by` in the query...

Comment: don't know also why this happens..i'm ordering by desc but now it displays as ascending

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all the result, and then just act on it as an array. So, for instance, you could shift the first result off the front, and then loop over any additional rows:

```
<?php

$sql = "YOUR QUERY";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// get first row
$firstRow = array_shift($rows);

// loop over remaining rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I think he specifically wanted an answer that avoided using `fetchall`

Comment: but fetchALL wastes memory from the experience of others...thanks :)

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Why? Have you got proof in the way of benchmarks that `fetchAll()` is “bad on memory” and “wasteful”, or are you just going on what you’ve read elsewhere? I imagine one `fetchAll()` is better than multiple `fetch()`s.

Comment: haven't tested it personally but a lot of people here reported memory problems using it

Comment: Can’t say I’ve had a problem with it in 3+ years.

Comment: @MartinBean: It depends on the size of the result set and number of columns. That said ive never had a problem unless i was then "hydrating" each result to an object(s) and it was greater than about 1000 results.