# PHP repeating SQL queries for each array's item efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

**What's the best way to run SQL query for each item in an array?**

I've got the *$array* of codes:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 12345
  [1] => 12346
  [3] => 12347
)
```

Now I'd like to run the following **SQL** query for each item in the *$array*:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` a WHERE a.`Code` = :code
```

**PHP I've been using:**

```
$results = array();

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(':code', $value);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $statement->execute();

    while (($results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== false) {
        echo $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: When a MySQL cursor is consumed you need to execute the query again. For as far as I know there is no way, besides MySQL caching, to avoid another query.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103202/how-to-fetch-2-times-in-mysql-pdo-without-fetchall

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `TABLE` a WHERE a.`Code` in :array

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running multiple queries, you could run one query and then loop over the results:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE` a WHERE a.`Code` IN (:codes);
```

Which would be something along these lines in your PHP:

```
$question_marks = str_repeat("?,", count($array_of_codes)-1) . "?"; 
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindParam(:codes, $question_marks);
$statement->execute($array_of_codes);

while (($results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) !== FALSE) {
  echo $results;
}
```

Where `$array_of_codes` is your PHP array containing the `Code` parameter for each result you want to look up.

**Credit where it's due** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373562/pdo-with-where-in-queries) helped with how to do WHERE...IN queries with PDO.