# How to reset object pointer after foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, loops, object, pdo, foreach

I want to iterate through an object 3 times, but the array methor 'reset' doen't work on object.

```
// DB connection works, fetch mode is FETCH_OBJ an cannot be changed for this question, code is simplified

$a = $pdo->query("SELECT name FROM items");
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    foreach ($a as $b)
        echo $b->name;
}
```

I only can iterate once.

Comment: Why do you run the outer loop?

Comment: to have 3 times a complete foreach loop

Comment: Just fetch all into an array. Thats the simple solution. But seems like you can set the cursor position - see f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14103276/3411766

Comment: What is the output of $a

Answer (score -1):

This is how you should do this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM items';
try {
  $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
  for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    echo($row['name']);
  }
  $stmt = null;
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  print $e->getMessage();
}
```

The ->fetch() command gets you the next line of your dataset.

Comment: Please look at my code. I want to repeat the foreach loop 3 times ( using for loop). I only get output for 1 complete iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: I edited the answer to fetch only the first 3 items.  You have to invoke the fetch() function for each row